# NSSortDescriptor not working

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have a core data entity called "TruckNumber" which has a string as it's only property.  The string is usually a 1-3 digit integer (as a string) but sometimes can have letters such as TMP9.  The name of the property is "itsNotANumma".  I am doing a fetch request to populate a picker, but they are not being sorted and I don't know why.  I've used this exact technique on other entities for other pickers and never had a problem.  Please help... Here's the relevant code:

```
// Fetch truck numbers
NSFetchRequest *truckNumberFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *truckEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TruckNumber" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[truckNumberFetchRequest setEntity:truckEntity];

// Sort Descriptor
NSSortDescriptor *truckDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itsNotANumma" ascending:YES];

NSArray *truckSortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:truckDescriptor, nil];
[inventoryFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:truckSortDescriptors];
error = nil;
NSArray *truckResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:truckNumberFetchRequest error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error while saving context: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

truckNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (TruckNumber *truckNumber in truckResults)
{
    [truckNumbersArray addObject:truckNumber.itsNotANumma];
}
```

Here is my data model for truck number:
[image]

These are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a simple typo:

```
[inventoryFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:truckSortDescriptors];
```

Should be:

```
[truckNumberFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:truckSortDescriptors];
```

I would assume anyway, from reading that code.

Comment: Grrrrrrrrrr....Thank you.  I will accept as answer in 9 minutes when it allows me.  Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees.  Thanks again.  I'll hang my head in shame for 30 seconds to salute you :-)

Comment: No problem! Glad to be the second pair of eyes to spot the typo :-).

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:(NSString*)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; 
}];
```

It works so perfectly if you have numbers in a range from 1-5000 or onwards.